# Send image in formData without file input

Tags: node.js, reactjs, forms, fs

I've been scouring the internet on this one, but I can't seem to find a situation exactly like what I'm trying to do....

I've built a React app (using CRA) which is used to import products from an existing eBay-like site (Reverb.com), make some small modifications, and then post them to a server which, in turn, manages the products on multiple eCommerce platforms. Pulling the data in from the Reverb.com API is easy enough; the problem comes when I submit the data to my local server's API. I need to post the product images from Reverb.com via formData without the user having to manually choose the files via a form input, but I don't have access to fs.createReadStream(). How can I get from an image URL to a file posted via formData?

Comment: Is there a specific format it needs to be in? For instance, does it have to be the raw, binary image data, or can it be base64 encoded?

Comment: I'm using multer to handle the image on the backend, so as far as I'm aware, I need the binary image data.

Comment: Hm. In that case, maybe try an XHR (or fetch) for the image, requesting the response type `blob`, and passing the blob into a FileReader to convert it into an array buffer? I unfortunately don't have enough experience with FileReaders or blobs to provide specific code in an answer, but hopefully this points you in the first direction?

Comment: Sadly, I wasn't able to get it to work. If anyone comes up with a solution, I'd be happy to have it, but for now, I was able to rework the back-end to also accept an array of URLs. From there, I saved the files with request and then proceeded as normal.